# BufferedReader not working as expected

Tags: java, bufferedreader

The below code is not getting executed completely after this line " bufferedReader.readLine(); ". The Program works fine when i execute the system command with
out mentioning IPAddress of the remote PC.

```
class Test    
{       
public static void main(String arg[])    
{    
     Process p;    
     Runtime runTime;    
     String process = null;    
     try {    
        runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();    
        p = runTime.exec("sc \\xx.xx.xx.xx query gpsvc");      // For Windows    
        InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();    
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);    
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);    
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();    
        process = "&";    
        while (line != null) {    
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();    
            process += line + "&";    
        }    
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(proc, "&");    
        System.out.println("token size "+st.countTokens());    
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {        
            String testData = st.nextToken();    
        bufferedReader.close();    
        inputStreamReader.close();    
        inputStream.close();    
        }    

     } catch (IOException e) {    
       System.out.println("Exception arise during the read Processes");    
       e.printStackTrace();    
     }    

}    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What output are you getting? What is happening - how do you know that its not working? What are you expecting the code to do? Its pretty hard to know how to help when you just say "its not working".

Comment: The execution is not getting complete.I am using exec function for executing the above command and `bufferedReader.readLine();` to read the response.The execution stops with this line and program goes into dead lock state .I am not getting any errors,outputs or exceptions as it has gone to blocked state

Answer (score 1):

Check your command inside `exec` method

`p = runTime.exec("sc \\xx.xx.xx.xx query gpsvc");`

The syntax is wrong here and if you execute this from command prompt, you will be prompted with the below question.

```
Would you like to see help for the QUERY and QUERYEX commands? [ y | n ]:
```

And the program wouldn't return until you enter y or n. Since the program is not terminating, you wouldn't be able to read the console output and that's the reason your program is getting stuck on `String line = bufferedReader.readLine();`

Comment: @Mr.Jiji Sasidharan Yes Boss, the command is working in command prompt. I have typed the same command 
"sc \\xx.xx.xx.xx query <service name>". It gave me the status of the service and it allowed 
to enter the next command